# CSS rotated object doesn't rotate until after animation is complete

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm creating a simple checkbox override in CSS and am trying to add an animation to make it appear. Because the checkmark is just a rotated rectangle with borders on the bottom and side, when I animate it, it isn't actually rotated until after the animation is complete. I tried adding the `transform:rotate()` to the animation keyframes, but for some reason when I do that, it doesn't animate at all. **How can I ensure that the checkmark remains rotated 45º throughout the animation process, and after it completes?**

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/L09h7jng/

#### HTML

```
<h3>Checkboxes</h3>
<div>
  <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-label">First Choice</label>
</div>
```

#### (S)CSS

$color-success: #12C376;

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    opacity: .25;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .8;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
    opacity: 1.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkbox + label:hover:before {
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: hover-color;
}

.checkbox + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid $color-piston;
}

.checkbox + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  content: '';
}

.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  //animation-name: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + label:after {
  display: block;
}

.checkbox + label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox + label:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 6px;
  height: 12px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: $color-success;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -moz-animation: bounce 0.3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  animation: bounce 0.3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid $color-piston;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your rotation inside your keyframe (do this for both webkit and normal):

```
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.25) rotate(15deg);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
    opacity: 1.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The `:after` should also have the rotate applied:

```
.checkbox + label:after {
  ...
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L09h7jng/4/

Comment: Yep, that's what I tried first - for some reason, it doesn't animate anymore when doing that.

Comment: @brandonscript it works for me on Chrome. Check the fiddle link I put

Comment: OH, I see what the problem is -- multiple transforms need to be done inline: `transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg)`.

Answer (score 0):

try to put rotate(45deg) to each line of all transform in animation progress...

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.25) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1.4;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.25) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```